# Wordpress posts not displaying through dedicated url

Tags: php, wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

A bit of an odd one. My news posts are not displaying through their unique URL.

Example:
- through the site you can see the news section and click through: 
http://disciplesldn.com/

- As a stand alone post, content disappears: 
  http://disciplesldn.com/2014/12/win-tickets-to-see-us-play-in-liverpool-on-boxing-day/

The theme is a custom build, using wordpress plugin 'types' for posting as single.php template file.

**single.php code example:**

```
<?php get_header(); the_post(); ?>

<section id="singlepost">
<div class="loadwrapper">

<div class="titleheaderpost">
<h1 class="singletitle"><? the_title(); ?></h1>
<p class="back"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="newslink">< back to News</a></p>
</div><!-- end of .titleheader -->

<div class="thenewscontent" id="thecontent">

<? the_content(); ?>

</div>
</div>
</section><!-- end of #singlepost -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your css on line 757 you have positioning styled on the `'singlepost'` id. you need to remove the left & top rules and the post displays correctly.

eg:

```
#singlepost {
     position: relative;
     /* left: 1200px; */
     /* top: -482px; */
     max-width: 960px;
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I was hoping it was more advanced than that :-) good spot. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
        <?php get_header();?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <section id="singlepost">
        <div class="loadwrapper">

        <div class="titleheaderpost">
        <h1 class="singletitle"><? the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p class="back"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="newslink">< back to News</a>  </p>
        </div><!-- end of .titleheader -->

        <div class="thenewscontent" id="thecontent">

        <? the_content(); ?>

        </div>
        </div>
        </section><!-- end of #singlepost -->
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```